# Can't find ORA-00907: missing the right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know what is wrong with this syntax.

```
SELECT Count (id_conv) AS NUM_CAMP 
FROM   csd_mx_mae_camp_dro 
WHERE  id_conv = (SELECT id_conv 
                  FROM   csd_mx_mae_conv_dro 
                  WHERE  num_cta = 60385300500) 
       AND id_cncpt = (SELECT A.id_cncpt 
                       FROM   csd_mx_mae_camp_dro A 
                              INNER JOIN csd_mx_mae_cncpt_dro B 
                                      ON A.id_cncpt = B.id_cncpt 
                       WHERE  ( ( flg_tipo_camp = 'A' 
                                  AND txt_nombr_clase_logic IS NOT NULL ) 
                                 OR ( flg_tipo_camp = 'C' ) ) 
                              AND txt_nom NOT IN ( 'Concepto' ) 
                              AND B.txt_cve = '84' 
                              AND A.id_conv = (SELECT id_conv 
                                               FROM   csd_mx_mae_conv_dro 
                                               WHERE  num_cta = 60385300500) 
                              AND rownum = 1 
                       ORDER  BY id_cmp) 
       AND flg_tipo_camp = 'A';
```

The expected result is 4, taking into account my records in the DB, however I have the error mentioned in the title (ORA-00907: missing the right parenthesis
00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"
* Cause:
* Action:
Error in the line: 171, column: 90).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your query. There might be something else causing the problem. Without more context I'm not able to help further.

Comment: `ORDER BY` in a subquery is useless and confuses the Oracle parser.

Comment: @stickybit - `ORDER BY` in a subquery is **sometimes (or perhaps even often)** useless, but there are cases when it is required (and syntactically valid). Where it is never valid is, as in the OP's case, in a *scalar* subquery. It is also illegal (and it would throw the same error) in an `IN` condition, used with a subquery rather than a list of hard-coded values.

Comment: Compare with: `select empno from (select empno from emp ORDER BY SAL) where ROWNUM 1` - a long-winded way to select the employee with the lowest salary (or one of the employees with the lowest salary, in the case of ties).

Comment: Es correcto, solo quitando el `ORDER BY` funcionó.

Comment: @mathguy: Yeah, you're right, I should have expressed that in a more differentiated manner. Thanks for putting that right.

Comment: @FernandoGonzálezFrías - do pay attention to what I said in my Reply though. Simply removing `ORDER BY` will allow your query to execute, but it may give the wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some subqueries where `ORDER BY` makes sense - and it is allowed by the syntax.

However, you use `ORDER BY` in a **scalar** subquery - one that is required to return a single value (one row / one column), and such subqueries do not allow `ORDER BY`.

You are using it incorrectly anyway (most likely) - you limit the number of rows to 1 by the condition `ROWNUM = 1`, which in conjunction with your `ORDER BY` probably means you wanted to order by `ID_CMP` and then take the first row from the result. That is not how it works; `ORDER BY` comes only **after** `ROWNUM` is assigned anyway. If that's what you were trying to do, remove `ORDER BY` as well as the condition on `ROWNUM`, and instead select `MIN(ID_CMP)` in the `SELECT` clause of the scalar subquery.

The specific error about the missing right parenthesis is caused by the `ORDER BY` clause: at that point, in a scalar subquery, the parser expects the closing parenthesis for the subquery, not any other token/clause/whatever.